# Inserting values directly into db-syntax in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

`INSERT`ing values without parameters is fully understandable why it shouldn't be allowed, where you e.g. want to prevent sql-injection. However I do not understand why it's still a big no doing the following as well:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Students] 
                    WHERE StudentID = " + studentID + ";";

                    int getID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

What's the harm in it when just `SELECT`ing? I don't really understand the point with parameters below. I'm not questioning it, I just want to know the reason why parameters is necessary and what consequences I could get from the code above instead using the option below.

```
var pStudentID = new SqlParameter("@studentID", SqlDbType.Int);
                pStudentID.Value = studentID;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pStudentID);
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't met [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons it's better to use parameters.

1. Sql Injection - Your first example would be susceptible to a sql injection attack.  What this means is if the studentID was being input from a web form, some one could use a '-- to comment out the select string and issue other commands against the database.
2. Prepare - If you use parameters you can prepare the sql statement, which is sort of a precompile of the syntax.  This can be slightly more performant in high volume situations.

Edit: I came across this video on reddit the other day, which is a great example of how sql injection works.[sql injection](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4pw8ih/running_an_sql_injection_attack/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarify :) I will stick with parameters from now on. Btw your reddit link doesn't work, "page not found"

Answer (score 1):

Assume this input:

```
var studentID = "''; drop table users;--"
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Students] 
                    WHERE StudentID = " + studentID + ";";
```

This would if calling this select delete the table users completely.

Parameters would help by approving only legitimate input to be added to the query.

Comment: Thanks for a great example :) That really made me realize how vulnerable the db is without parameters.